# How can I erase hard disk if SuperDrive is broken (OS 10.6.8)?

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, disk-utility, optical-drive

I have an old MacBook running OS 10.6.8 which I want to recycle, but its internal SuperDrive doesn't work, so I can't use the install disk to do it.  I tried plugging in Apple's external USB SuperDrive which I bought when I upgraded to a MacBook Pro which has no internal SuperDrive, but the external SuperDrive doesn't accept the disc; it's as if the old MacBook doesn't recognize the external drive.  I'm thus at a loss as to how to proceed to wipe the hard disk.

Comment: Maybe asking a second question to analyze/solve the issue with the external drive would help as well

Comment: By Apple's design, their external super drive will only work with Apple computers which did not ship with a built-in drive. A third-party USB drive should generally work with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create a bootable USB stick with some kind of recovery LiveCD (Ubuntu, BackTrack, ...)

I recommend using Ubuntu because it is the easiest to create.

There is a little tutorial on Ubuntu's website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx 
(If you Have trouble be sure to ask a question on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com))

After you have a recovery usb wipe the disk using your favorite tool. I found a nice tutorial on ['How to geek'](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15037/use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-securely-wipe-your-pcs-hard-drive/), but it's a bit outdated.
(Tip: download wipe from the software center, not from synaptic)

Comment: Please add some information as this alone is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your MacBook is capable of upgrading to 10.7 or newer (the current 10.9, OS X Mavericks is available for free from the AppStore, 10.7 - Lion and 10.8 - Mountain Lion are for sale on DVD at the apple online store for under €20,-) you can use the disk utility from the recovery partition (after installing a newer version of OS X, in this case from a bootable USB Drive) by holding cmd + r during boot.

Else, if you are not afraid to open the MacBook you can also remove the drive, put it in an external enclosure and format it with another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you borrow or purchase an inexpensive external DVD drive to see if you can boot from the install disc. This [Sanyo drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009QBIZ60) is only $28US and works just fine read/write on all the Macs I've attached it to, old and new. I can't guarantee you will be able to *boot* from it, as I've never tried that, but if it won't boot your laptop you can always send it back for a refund.